# UI not responding during a service call in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, background-process

I am fetching data from a web service call, during same time i call a pop up page with animation but it stops when service is called and comes back after getting the data. I have used Task. Async as well but still is not responsive to UI. The pop up shows the animation as loader.

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                var indicatorPopup = new CustomIndicatorPopUp();
                //This is my pop up call
                await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(indicatorPopup);
                //Below is my web service call
                obj.LoadData();
                //Closing the pop up
                await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
            });
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Pop up page xaml is as below:

```
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SP"

             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
              xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
         x:Class="CustomIndicatorPopUp"
             >

<pages:PopupPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <local:DialogsResources />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</pages:PopupPage.Resources>

<pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <animations:MoveAnimation
        PositionIn="Center"
        PositionOut="Center" />
</pages:PopupPage.Animation>

<Grid
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        Padding="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition
                Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition
                Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <local:CustomActivityIndicator
            Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="Indicator"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <Label
            Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            Text="Loading" />
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class CustomActivityIndicator : ContentView
{
    private bool _playing = false;
    private Animation _animation;

    public CustomActivityIndicator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _animation = new Animation(
            callback: d => Wrapper.RotationY = d,
            start: 0,
            end: 360,
            easing: Easing.Linear);

        _playing = true;
        _animation.Commit(Wrapper, "Loop", length: 1000, repeat: () => _playing);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _playing = false;
        _animation = null;
    }
}
```

I Have tried activtiyIndicator but it is not working properly, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to separate the push/pop action with load data action. I mean, first: `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    var indicatorPopup = new CustomIndicatorPopUp();
                    //This is my pop up call
                    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(indicatorPopup);                   
                });` Then  `obj.LoadData();` At last:  `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
                });`.

Comment: Need more info, where exactly is the Task.Run is called? why run on different thread only to again run on main thread!!!!